# How can i Create this Object To Use with Service.Put / Post Json

Tags: json, vb.net, codeigniter, object

i am making a few trys with Json and Post Method from Vb.net

I Create a body object with the Keys

dim body as object

```
body = New With {
            Key .title = tittle,
            Key .price = price,
            how can i put and if here?
            if 1 > 2 then
            key .test = 1000
            end if
            }
```

i need to create one body, or join two body in one:

```
body = New With {
            Key .title = tittle,
            Key .price = price,
            }

body1 = new with { 
            key .test = 1000
             }
```

bodyFinall= body + body

or something like that. is possible?
really thanks